# How to install DBATools

Tags: powershell, sql

I want to install on my Desktop DBAtools utility. I expect that it will help me to explore SQL more ..

I found reference to it at this location https://dbatools.io/commands/

I downloaded the package dbatools.0.9.475.nupkg to my Desktop.

Unfortunately I don't have Admin privileges on my PC.
I tried to use Power Shell and run this command like it was recommended:

```
PS W:\Software\dbatools> Install-Module -Name dbatools
Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Module -Name dbatools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Could someone suggest a workaround to open .nupkg but don't know how to do it?
Maybe dbatools has other format than .nupkg? I can't do much without admin rights.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser dbatools`

Comment: I just tried and got exact same error as I reported above

Comment: Go to: https://dbatools.io/download/, download the ZIP via **method 3** as mentioned there, then extract to the location just as they indicate there. This may be `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` but check to confirm on your system. See if that will work for your need so you can use those tools.

Comment: Pimp Juice IT, Thanks so much, I'm all set now. I was not able to put it anywhere in my $env:PSMODULEPATH because or lack of permission. The only place that I was able to put it (which was listed in $env:PSMODULEPATH) was W:\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\dbatools>. Btw I had to create a few subdirectories here because they did not exist. Now I'll try if it'll work for me :) . Thanks for advice.

Comment: Eventually I copied the folder BUT I can't do anything with it. I am not much familiar neither with Powershell not with dbatools. I simply wanted to play with it and use some commands and etc. But I'm completely lost. Could someone help me? I mean provide some simple approaches of usage. E.g. I want to list all databases on the server; or I want to list tables or etc. Just starting with the simple things. Whatever I try I've got an error. Just simple set of instruction to start with. Maybe this utility is not for me... but I want to at least try it ..
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: The correct thing to do is to contact your local IT support staff with this request. First, the computer is not yours if you do not have admin rights, and so anything you do must be within the policy limits of the organization that owns the computer. Second, your local IT staff will be the ones able to install this package if it meets policy requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your download location
2. Left click the `dbatools` folder or under whatever name you saved it.
3. Left click the version folder.  (Mine is currently 1.0.9)
4. Open the install PowerShell code.
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to select all and copy it.
6. Open PowerShell with administration rights.
7. Paste and run.